# Uncrustify vs. Objective-C: method colon alignment

Tags: objective-c, uncrustify

I'm trying to get Uncrustify to work for me with Objective-C code. Ordinarily, I'd like multi-line
method signature declaration/implementations to be colon-aligned, like

```
- (void)doSomethingWithThis:(id)this
                       that:(id)that
                      other:(id)other;
```

However, sometimes the first parameter is not long enough to make that happen. In that case, I'd like to fall back to simple indentation, e.g.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier
    completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

However, here's what Uncrustify does for me in that case:

```
- (void)                    application:(UIApplication *)application
    handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier
                      completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

Um, yuch. Can I get Uncrustify to do what I want?

Here are some selected settings:

```
align_var_def_colon                       = true
align_oc_msg_spec_span                    = 1
align_oc_msg_colon_span                   = 1   
align_oc_msg_colon_first                  = true
align_oc_decl_colon                       = true
```

Feel free to ask about more detail in the comments.